# Can't write a type declaration in playground of Haskell IDE

Tags: haskell

I'm writing Haskell with the [‎Haskell on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/haskell/id841285201?l=en&mt=12) tool.

I can't write a type declaration with the playground of [‎Haskell on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/haskell/id841285201?l=en&mt=12).

The following syntax, without type declarations, is OK:

```
data Foo = A | B
data Bar = C | D
data FooBar = FooBar Foo Bar

x = FooBar A C
```

The following writing style is not acceptable:

```
data Foo = A | B
data Bar = C | D
data FooBar = FooBar Foo Bar

x :: FooBar
x = FooBar A C
```

The error message

```
<playground>:5:1: error: Variable not in scope: x :: FooBar
```

Why can't I write the type declarations?

[image]

Comment: Seems like it’s running it through GHCi (if it’s using GHC). Try wrapping it in a multiline declaration `:{  <newline> x :: FooBar <newline> x = FooBar A C <newline> :}`. `<newline>` means a newline character, since this is just a comment.

Comment: Just for background, since it’s evaluating each line one by one in GHCi, `x :: FooBar` is interpreted as an *expression* `(x :: FooBar)` (i.e., the variable `x`, annotated with type `FooBar`) rather than a type signature, and failing because `x` isn’t defined yet at that point. In addition to using a multiline command as @cole mentions, or writing your code in a `.hs` file per @chi’s answer, you can also solve this by using a semicolon to put the definition on a single line: `x :: FooBar; x = FooBar A C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the screenshots [on their page](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/haskell/id841285201?l=en&mt=12) you should have a window with multiple panes.

The left pane should be named `SomeNameHere.hs` and you should write your code there. It should handle multi-line definitions just fine, since it looks line this code is passed to GHC.

The middle pane, with the test tube icon, is instead used for single-line experiments, which will be evaluated in GHCi so to observe their results (right pane).

My guess is that you didn't create the left pane. Try the menus -- there should be a "new project" or "new Haskell file" entry. The "show or hide area" buttons also look promising.